# Cat health consideration regarding the coronavirus

Tags: cats, health, safety

We have a two year old Persian cat with some kidney problems. We live in Iran, which these days is not a good place relative to potential coronavirus outbreaks because of the government not giving true information about it. We think we will get the virus some time in the future.

In this condition we would like to know, if we did contract the coronavirus, how can we protect our cat from our infection?

If we become unable to protect ourselves, I don't know how could take care of him and who would accept him. I think he must trained to survive in nature, could I train him at this during his time period? If yes, how?

Comment: it is fine you are thinking of taking care of your cat but as i understand it about 80% of people contracting the virus do have mild symptoms so try not to worry.

Answer (score 11):

Cats and dogs can carry several types of coronaviruses; this does not mean the cat or dog will be ill, but it is possible for both dogs and cats to get ill from some of the coronaviruses.

The type of coronavirus in circulation now, COVID-19, has not been confirmed to cause illness in cats and dogs. Too little is known as of now to say if cats and dogs can be carriers of the virus or if they can transmit virus to people.

One dog has tested positive for COVID-19; it is not confirmed that the dog is a carrier of the virus. It might be traces of the virus on the dog. New tests have been taken and the result is pending.

Source for more information about COVID-19 and pets could be [found there](https://www.cnbc.com/2020/02/28/a-dog-in-hong-kong-tests-positive-for-the-coronavirus-who-confirms.html) (source: cnbc.com).

Edit: A cat in Belgium [is the first cat that has been confirmed to be infected with COVID-19](https://www.cats.org.uk/help-and-advice/coronavirus/statement-relating-to-cat-in-belgium-with-coronavirus-covid-19) (source: cats.org.uk). The cat got the infection from the owner and got ill one week after the owner did ,as far as I know both cat and owner are recovering.

There is still no indication that a cat or a dog can infect people with COVID-19.

Answer (score 6):

**Updated: The WHO has since removed this information from their "Myth Busters" page, likely in light of the case(s) cited in trond hansen's answer.**

There is currently no evidence that domestic cats or dogs are affected by COVID-19:

> **Can pets at home spread the new coronavirus (2019-nCoV)?**
>   At present, there is no evidence that companion animals/pets such as dogs or cats can be infected with the new coronavirus. However, it is always a good idea to wash your hands with soap and water after contact with pets. This protects you against various common bacteria such as E.coli and Salmonella that can pass between pets and humans.

Source: [World Health Organization](https://www.who.int/emergencies/diseases/novel-coronavirus-2019/advice-for-public/myth-busters)

Answer (score -2):

I just saw this article on my local vets website about pets and corona virus. It has some preventative suggestions on there, they look similar to what we already know though.

https://allambievet.com.au/news/can-pets-get-coronavirus-disease

Comment: Hi and welcome to Pets, could you please elaborate a bit more in your answer? I mean the link is helpful, but generally the concept is that answers are better if they are self-sufficent - for example, in case the link gets defunct. Maybe you could cite the most relevant fragments of this article and insert them in your answer please? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I will. I have found some other information since and will share those too.