# Is it okay to neuter my cat although he had been exposed to FIP cat?

Tags: cats, health, fear, neutering

I have two male cats, both are stray which decided to live in my house this past year. 
one cat is less than a year, 10 months perhaps, and other is probably older than 2 years, both are not neutered yet.

i want to neuter them, but I'm scared with the risks.

I'm scared because I had a cat suspected with [FIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feline_infectious_peritonitis) before they came. They have been exposed with the FIP cat for 2 months, but they never share litter box.

Now the FIP cat had been gone for three months already, and the other two cats are still healthy and active. I want them to be neuter, but I'm afraid the stress caused by neuter surgery will lead them to develop FIP, according to many articles, spaying/neutering is included as stressor that might lead to coronavirus mutation.

Since we are in pandemic era of covid-19, is it possible that might be [FCoV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feline_coronavirus) also in outbreak? I have seen another cat near my house that has developed the same nervous system symptom of FIP.

I wonder if i should delay or never neuter my cat at all.

I know i might be sounds overstretched and paranoid, but it's true, I'm really scared, that's why i put the question here.

I live in a country where testing body titer of certain virus in cat is available for public due to the lack of development of veterinary

Comment: You're letting the news get to you. It's perfectly fine. My family had a cat who recovered from FIP, was neutered, and lived about 17 years after that with no problems whatsoever.

Answer (score 6):

Even if your cat is infected with FIP, the neutering is safe to do. I have had this done to a feral cat I had a couple of years ago (actually it was done at the same time as a tooth was extracted as a result of FIP).

I cannot answer how safe it is to spay a female cat that has FIP, but I do not think the risk is significantly elevated in female cats.

Cats can get a number of coronaviruses, but COVID-19 is not one of the ones that can infect cats or dogs.

This question is related to the corona part of your question: [Cat health consideration vs coronavirus](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/27196/cat-health-consideration-vs-coronavirus)

Neutering a cat is a simple and easy operation that causes very little stress for the cat and your cat will not need any special care after this have been done.