# Could my dog get infected with SARS-CoV-2 coronavirus and suffer from COVID-19?

Tags: dogs, health, diseases

I have heard, that dogs too could get the actual coronavirus. Is this real?

Comment: related https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/27196/cat-health-consideration-regarding-the-coronavirus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coronaviruses are a large group of viruses, that most animals deals with every day without signs of illness.

The "new" coronavirus called "SARS-CoV-2" causing risk for health in humans, causes nearly no health issues in dogs.

But there are two other ("older") coronaviruses, that infects dogs with signs of illness, mainly diarrhoea. These viruses have no effect on the human health.

Additonal: in science there are two dogs noted, that were infected by SARS-CoV-2. Both cases occurred in Hongkong (very high COVID-19 density) and parts of the virus were found at the blood of both animals. But both cases had NO infectious (means whole, functional) virus in their body.

Source is the website of German Dog Association (VDH) publishing an [interview](https://www.vdh.de/corona/statementut.html) with the director of the institute for animal hygiene and veterinarian association at the university of Leipzig.